# Inject all implementations of an interface using Dagger

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I have an interface `BaseProcessor` and several implementations of it.

Now, in a class (`ValidationComponent`) I want to have a list of all my BaseProcessor implementations, like this : `List<BaseProcessor> processors;`

All the implementations have an `@Inject` constructor.

Now, currently I am doing this :
In `ValidationComponent` class,

```
    private List<BaseProcessor> processors;

    @Inject
    public ValidationComponent(@NonNull final ProcessorImpl1 processor1,
                               @NonNull final ProcessorImpl2 processor2,
                               @NonNull final ProcessorImpl3 processor3) {
        this.processors = new ArrayList<>();
        this.processors.add(processor1);
        this.processors.add(processor2);
        this.processors.add(processor3);
    }
```

In order to pass the implementation into the constructor, dagger is creating instances of these implementations because, as mentioned, they all have `@Inject` constructors.

Now, instead of passing each concrete implementation in the constructor, can I somehow use Dagger to create all of these implementation instances for me?

I know that it is possible in the Spring framework by annotating implementations with `@Component` spring annotation. Is there a way in Dagger?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [multibindings](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/multibindings.html), specifically by adding an [`@IntoSet`](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/multibindings/IntoSet.html) binding in an abstract module.

```
@Module
abstract class ProcessorBindingModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoSet
    abstract BaseProcessor bindProcessor1(ProcessorImpl1 processor);

    // ...

}
```

This makes `Set<BaseProcessor>` available for injection:

```
    private List<BaseProcessor> processors;

    @Inject
    public ValidationComponent(@NonNull final Set<BaseProcessor> processors) {
        this.processors = new ArrayList<>(processors);
        // or just make the field a Set instead of a List
    }
```